# Can not import customize module in openERP

Tags: python, odoo

i have done simple customize module in `openerp` with using python and xml. but I cannot import in openerp. My module is not shown in openerp.

this is `__init__py`

```
import os
os.environ['TZ'] = 'UTC' # Set the timezone...
import time              # ... *then* import time.
del os
del time

# The hard-coded super-user id (a.k.a. administrator, or root user).
SUPERUSER_ID = 1

import addons
import cli
import conf
import loglevels
import modules
import netsvc
import osv
import pooler
import release
import report
import service
import sql_db
import tools
import workflow
import sim
# backward compatilbility
# TODO: This is for the web addons, can be removed later.
wsgi = service
wsgi.register_wsgi_handler = wsgi.wsgi_server.register_wsgi_handler
# Is the server running in multi-process mode (e.g. behind Gunicorn).
# If this is True, the processes have to communicate some events,
# e.g. database update or cache invalidation. Each process has also
# its own copy of the data structure and we don't need to care about
# locks between threads.
multi_process = False

# vim:expandtab:smartindent:tabstop=4:softtabstop=4:shiftwidth=4:
```

this is `__openerp__.py`

```
{
'name': 'Student Information Management',
'version': '0.1',
'category': 'Tools',
'description': """This module is for the Student Information Management.""",
'author': 'Mir Nauman&nbsp;Tahir',
'website': 'http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/',
'depends': ['base'],
'init_xml': [],
'update_xml': ['sim_view.xml'],
'demo_xml': [],
'installable': True,
'active': True,

}
```

this is sim_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<!-- ============== student================= -->
<!-- 1st part of the sim_view start-->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="student_form">
<field name="name">Student</field>
<field name="model">sim.student</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string="Student" version="7.0">
<field name="name"/>
<field name="student_name"/>
<field name="father_name"/>
<field name="gender"/>
<field name="contact_no"/>
</form>
</field>
</record>
<!-- 1st part of the sim_view end-->
<!--2nd part of the sim_view start-->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="student_tree">
<field name="name">Student</field>
<field name="model">sim.student</field>
<field name="type">tree</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<tree string="Student">
<field name="name"/>
<field name="student_name"/>
<field name="father_name"/>
<field name="gender"/>
<field name="contact_no"/>
</tree>
</field>
</record>
<!--2nd part of the sim_view end-->
<!-- 3rd part of the sim_view start-->
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_student">
<field name="name">Student</field>
<field name="res_model">sim.student</field>
<field name="view_type">form</field>
<field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
<!--3rd part of the sim_view end-->
<!--4th part of the sim_view start-->
<menuitem&nbsp;name="SIM/Student/StudentInfo" id="menu_sim_student" action="action_student"/>
<!--4th part of the sim_view end-->
</data>
</openerp>
```

this sim.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields

class student(osv.osv):
    _name = "sim.student"
    _description = "This table is for keeping personal data of student"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Registration Number',size=256,required=True),
        'student_name': fields.char('Student Name',size=256,required=True),
        'father_name': fields.char('Father Name',size=256),
        'gender':fields.selection([('male','Male'),('female','Female')],'Gender'),
        'contact_no':fields.char('Contact Number',size=256)
    }
student()
```

I cannot see my module in openerp. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work fine. Try this. Update all your files.

```
__openerp__.py   File

{
'name': 'Student Information Management',
'version': '0.1',
'category': 'Tools',
'description': """This module is for the Student Information Management.""",
'author': 'Mir Nauman&nbsp;Tahir',
    'website': 'http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/',
'depends': ['base'],
'data': ['sim_view.xml'],
'demo': [],
'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'application': True,

}


 __init__.py File

import sim




sim.py File


from openerp.osv import fields, osv
class student(osv.osv):
_name = "sim.student"
_description = "This table is for keeping personal data of student"
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Registration Number',size=256,required=True),
    'student_name': fields.char('Student Name',size=256,required=True),
    'father_name': fields.char('Father Name',size=256),
    'gender':fields.selection([('male','Male'),('female','Female')],'Gender'),
    'contact_no':fields.char('Contact Number',size=256)
}
student()


sim_view.xml File

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<!-- ============== student================= -->
<!-- 1st part of the sim_view start-->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="student_form">
<field name="name">Student</field>
<field name="model">sim.student</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string="Student" version="7.0">
<group>
<field name="name"/>
<field name="student_name"/>
<field name="father_name"/>
<field name="gender"/>
<field name="contact_no"/>
</group>
</form>
</field>
</record>
<!-- 1st part of the sim_view end-->
<!--2nd part of the sim_view start-->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="student_tree">
<field name="name">Student</field>
<field name="model">sim.student</field>
<field name="type">tree</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<tree string="Student">
<field name="name"/>
<field name="student_name"/>
<field name="father_name"/>
<field name="gender"/>
<field name="contact_no"/>
</tree>
</field>
</record>
<!--2nd part of the sim_view end-->
<!-- 3rd part of the sim_view start-->
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_student">
<field name="name">Student</field>
<field name="res_model">sim.student</field>
<field name="view_type">form</field>
<field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
<!--3rd part of the sim_view end-->
<!--4th part of the sim_view start-->
<menuitem name="SIM/Student/StudentInfo" id="menu_sim_student"  
      action="action_student"/>
<!--4th part of the sim_view end-->
</data>
</openerp>
```

After updating all your files, Restart the server, update module list and find your 
    module in Settings > Modules > Installed Modules - remove installed from there and write your module's name (i.e sim) over there.

Hope this will definitely work.

Comment: stil not display modules in openerp. i have doubt in my path home/openerp-7.0-10240106-002615/openerp/addons/sim. is it correct or not?

Comment: then what mistake i do?

Comment: Everything seems proper at my side. This should have to work at your side also. Nevertheless do one thing, create new database and check again.

Comment: it is work Thank you. i have worked in wrong path so that my module was not show in openerp.

Answer (score 2):

In order to see a custom module in OpenERP 7, it must first be in the `addons` directory.

Go to `Settings` > `Modules` > `Update Modules List`

Click `Update`

You must have `Technical Features` enabled for the user you are logged in as.

Then go to `Settings` > `Modules` > `Installed Modules`

Remove the `[Installed]` filter and search for your custom module.

Custom modules will not appear in `Settings` > `Modules` > `Apps` because that view will only display `Modules/Apps` that are found online.

Comment: I checked as you said, but same error. this file path home/server/addons/lab

Answer (score 2):

The only issue i can see here is that your `openerp.py` file name is not correct the name should be `__openerp__`, plus in the `__init__.py` file you should import the `sim.py` file, and no need to import all of those modules that you wrote there, keep only the necessary libraries and modules you need.

Answer (score 1):

Once again Make sure that you have put your module inside addons directory where all
    the other modules exists. not inside server's addons, it should be inside main addons.

```
   Hope this will solve your problem
```

Comment: my folder placed on server/openerp/addons

Comment: Wrong place. Thatz why you are not finding your module in module list.
put your module in main addons directory where all the other modules are placed after that restart server and update your module list. You will see your module. or just follow the steps as Ethan Furman and Rich G have said. This will solve your issue for sure. Do try this.

Comment: hi i changed folde in this path openerp-7.0-20140106-002615/openerp/addons. still same error (module not visible in openerp)

Comment: can you tell me what are the other folders reside in that same folder.
give some of module name that are in the same directory where you have 
kept your module.

Comment: account_chart, sale, base_vat

Comment: Well from my side I have installed your module and it works fine after doing some changes. Now you have kept your module at right place. Just 
update all your files as I have done in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Zak said, `__init__.py` need only need to import the `sim` which is the python file you are using in the module. In `__openerp__.py` file, i cant find any error. The problem I found is in the `sim.py` file!!! You are importing only `fields` from `openerp.osv`. Your class is now inheriting the osv folder. Your class should inherit the osv file's osv class(class name: Model ). For openerp functionality, you have to import `osv` from `openerp.osv`. Please modify the sim.py with `from openerp.osv import osv, fields`.

Comment: still same error can´t display in openerp. this is my path home/server/addons/lab. how is connecting those coding with openerp.

Comment: which openerp version you are using? if its 7, then change the key 'update_xml' to 'data'.

Comment: please check the permissions of your module and files

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 bala root  435 Jan  8 17:34 __init__.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bala root  380 Jan  8 17:35 __openerp__.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bala root  509 Jan  8 17:36 sim.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bala root 1469 Jan  8 10:12 sim_view.xml

Comment: please check the permissions of other openerp addons modules.If the permissions of your module and other addon modules is different, then change the  user and group of your module same as that of other addons modules.

Answer (score 0):

f you want to see a custom module in OpenERP 7, it must first be in the addons directory.

Go to **Settings > Modules > Update Modules List**

Click Update

You must have Technical Features enabled for the user you are logged in as.

Then go to **Settings > Modules > Installed Modules**

Remove the [Installed] filter and search for your custom module.

Custom modules will not appear in **Settings > Modules > Apps** because that view will only display Modules/Apps that are found online.