# how to add a field in res.partner in open erp

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, openerp-7

I'm new to OpenErp.
I want to Add a new field "mother_name" in res.partner.So i have added the following code to res.partner.py 
In column's i have add like this

```
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Name', size=128, required=True, select=True),
    'date': fields.date('Date', select=1),
    'title': fields.many2one('res.partner.title', 'Title'),
    'parent_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Related Company'),
    'child_ids': fields.one2many('res.partner', 'parent_id', 'Contacts', domain=[('active','=',True)]), # force "active_test" domain to bypass _search() override    
    'ref': fields.char('Reference', size=64, select=1),
    'date_delivery': fields.date('Expected Delivery Date'),
    'mother_ln': fields.char('Mother', size=64),
     .
     .
     .
     }
```

Now in res_partner_view.xml . I'm using the following code

```
        <record id="view_partner_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">res.partner.tree</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field eval="8" name="priority"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Contacts">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="function" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="phone"/>
                    <field name="email"/>
                    <field name="user_id" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="is_company" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="country" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="country_id" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="date_delivery"/>
                    <field name="mother_ln"/>
                    <field name="parent_id" invisible="1"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>


<record id="view_partner_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">res.partner.form</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field eval="1" name="priority"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Partners" version="7.0">
                <sheet>
                    <field name="image" widget='image' class="oe_left oe_avatar" options='{"preview_image": "image_medium", "size": [90, 90]}'/>
                    <div class="oe_title">
                        <div class="oe_edit_only">
                            <label for="name"/> (
                            <field name="is_company" on_change="onchange_type(is_company)" class="oe_inline"/> <label for="is_company" string="Is a Company?"/>)
                        </div>
                        <h1>
                            <field name="name" default_focus="1" placeholder="Name" />
                        </h1>
                        <field name="parent_id"
                            placeholder="Company"
                            domain="[('is_company', '=', True)]" context="{'default_is_company': True, 'default_supplier': supplier}"
                            attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company','=', True),('parent_id', '=', False)]}"
                            on_change="onchange_address(use_parent_address, parent_id)"/>
                        <!-- <field name="category_id" widget="many2many_tags" placeholder="Tags..."/> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="oe_right oe_button_box" name="buttons"> </div>

                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <label for="type" attrs="{'invisible': [('parent_id','=', False)]}"/>
                            <div attrs="{'invisible': [('parent_id','=', False)]}" name="div_type">
                                <field class="oe_inline"
                                    name="type"/>
                            </div>

                            <label for="street" string="Address"/>
                            <div>
                                <field name="use_parent_address" class="oe_edit_only oe_inline"
                                       on_change="onchange_address(use_parent_address, parent_id)"
                                       attrs="{'invisible': [('parent_id','=', False),('use_parent_address','=',False)]}"/>
                                <label for="use_parent_address" class="oe_edit_only" attrs="{'invisible': [('parent_id','=', False),('use_parent_address','=',False)]}"/>
                                <button name="open_parent" type="object" string="(edit company address)" class="oe_link oe_edit_only"
                                        attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('parent_id','=', False),('use_parent_address','=',False)]}"/>
                                <field name="street" placeholder="Street..."  attrs="{'readonly': [('use_parent_address','=',True)]}"/>
                                <field name="street2"  attrs="{'readonly': [('use_parent_address','=',True)]}"/>
                                <div class="address_format">
                                    <field name="city" placeholder="City" style="width: 40%%" attrs="{'readonly': [('use_parent_address','=',True)]}"/>
                                    <field name="state_id" class="oe_no_button" placeholder="State" style="width: 37%%" options='{"no_open": True}' on_change="onchange_state(state_id)" attrs="{'readonly': [('use_parent_address','=',True)]}"/>
                                    <field name="zip" placeholder="ZIP" style="width: 20%%" attrs="{'readonly': [('use_parent_address','=',True)]}"/>
                                </div>
                                <field name="country_id" placeholder="Country" class="oe_no_button" options='{"no_open": True}' attrs="{'readonly': [('use_parent_address','=',True)]}"/>
                            </div>

                        </group>
                        <group>
                          <!-- We Don't require Job Position for Customer -->
                          <!--   <field name="function" placeholder="e.g. Sales Director"
                                attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company','=', True)]}"/> -->
                            <field name="phone" placeholder="e.g. +32.81.81.37.00"/>
                            <field name="mobile"/>
                            <field name="fax"/>
                            <field name="email" widget="email"/>
                            <!-- <field name="title" domain="[('domain', '=', 'contact')]"
                                options='{"no_open": True}' attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company','=', True)]}" /> -->
                        </group>
                        <field name="date_delivery"/>
                        <field name="mother_ln"/>
                        </group>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                 </record>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Better is you inherit that code and add your field rather doing changes to main code.
for your py file 

class res_partner(osv.osv):

 _inherit= 'res.partner'

 _columns = {
     'mother_ln': fields.char('Mother', size=64),
     'father_name': fields.char('Father', size=64),
 # this is comment. -> you can add as many types of fields as you want - eg. char ,
    #                   boolean, float, integer, one2many, many2one etc. 
 }

res_partner()


for your xml file :-

<record id="view_res_partner_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">view.res.partner.inherited</field>
  <field name="model">res.partner</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="date_delivery" position="after">
        <field name="mother_ln" />
        <field name="father_name" />
<!--comment- likewise this is your view, add all your fields here in view -->
    </field>
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: As you have said you are new to OpenERP, you can create custom module and add this two files there. For your reference, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971737/can-not-import-customize-module-in-openerp/20988029#20988029

Hope this will help to create custom module. and use above xml and py code for those files respectively. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But i need to add more field's when i create a new customer.If i inherit the res.partner to new thing.How can i link my new files to Create button (when i want to create a new customer)

Comment: more field's to same object or other object?? can you elaborate what exactly you want

Comment: In existing Creating customer form i need to add more fields like Mother name,Father name ,Child name and Child DOB.I need to add the above fields to create New Customer form. Can you please help me, how to add new fields to existing object or Create Customer form

Comment: Ok Mansi , Now my question is how can i relate the new files to onclick of Create button ??

Comment: ok. for that you have to call wizard over there. I can see that you are not that aware with Openerp. So fierst of all read this, 
link- 

slideshare.net/openobject/openerp-technical-memento

 now to call wizard through wizard, set your button type as action and add your wizard file in name attribute.

                        <button name="%(action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv)d" string="Create Invoice"
                            type="action" class="oe_highlight"/>

Comment: THank's Mansi.           i have one more doubt.If i change xml files of any modules in the addon's the modifications are done.Now if i copy these changed xml files to other machine i can see the changes.Similary if i add more fields using the user interface i couldn't see those changes after i copy those files into other machine can u help me in this??

Comment: the reason for that is that whatever change you have made in your xml files are in files, and you are transfering files, not Database.
so if you want all that changes of user inteface to another machine. Do one thing backup your database in this machine. now restore that in another machine. this will solve your issue

Comment: @PKN if you got you answer the kindly accept and give a upvote 
..
appreciate the help

Comment: Thank's Mansi your answer was useful.

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal i accepted the answer and it is saying that i cann't upvote i need 15 rep to do it.