# Why is it taking more time, When i upgrade a module in Openerp

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, radix

I'm new to Openerp.I have modified the base module and when i goto installed modules and search for BASE module and click upgrade button it is nearly taking 5mins.Can any one please say me how can i reduce the time that is taking for up-gradation of existing module.
Note: I have Messaging,Sales,Invoicing,Human-resource,Tools and Reporting modules installed,is it due to i have more modules installed??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what going here just same answer copied by other user and answer here in few mintues

Comment: Let me tell you that its just coincidence, and both answers are not the same may be you have not read properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As you have said that You are new to OpenERP, Let me tell you something which would be very helpful to you. i.e Never Do changes in Standard modules not in base. If you      want to add or remove any functionality of any module, you can do this by creating a customzed module. in which inherit the object you want, and do the changes as per 
  your requirement.
- Now regarding the time spent when upgrading base module, This is because when you update base module it will automatically update all the other modules which are already installed (in your case - Sales,Invoicing,Human-resource,Tools and Reporting) as base is the main module on which all the other modules are dependedent.

  So, Better is to do your changes in customized module and upgrade that perticular module only, not the base.

  Hope this will help you.

Comment: can u please share a example how to inherit the existing module and to add fields to it.I tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325582/how-to-add-a-field-in-res-partner-in-open-erp/21325846?noredirect=1#21325846) but i couldn't do it.

Comment: yeah sure. will create blog and explain in detail. and give you that link very soon.

Answer (score 0):

why you going in installed modules and search for base module and update it?

you have to only update that module in which you have done changes in xml file not event py file.

if you have changes in xml file of those module you have to update only those module.

if you going to update base module it will update all module which installed in your databae,

because every module depend on base, we can call base is the kernal of our all modules, all module depend on this module, if you update base it will going to update all modules

if you have done some changes in sale then you have to search for sale and update the only 
sale module not go to update base module

regards,